# How to concat a string and a props in React

Tags: reactjs, concatenation

This is just a question to clarify what I know and understand about React concatenating string and props. I have a simple code like

```
const foo = bar?'test--${bar}':''
```

When I am logging out `foo`, it shows `test--${bar}` instead of `test--whatever`. If I try to do

```
const foo = bar?'test--' + bar:''
```

It will give me the answer I am expecting to be. Can someone explain to me why. I was just started learning React. I scanned through some questions here and they said the best way to concat string and props is to do the first one but why its not working on me. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: And yes, this type of concatenation isn't specific to React. It is a feature of ES6.

Comment: Yeah agreed! Maybe because I am learning React that is why I think its because of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are not using template literals.

Try it like this:

```js
const bar = "typo";
const foo = bar ? `test--${bar}` : "nope";

console.log(foo);
```

Reference article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks (`) instead of single quotes and it will work.

```js
//Correct
const foo = bar?`test--${bar}`:'whatever';

//Incorrect
const foo = bar?'test--${bar}':'whatever'
```